# Can Python OS operations be vectorized (Ex: os.rename)?

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I have a list of directories that need to be renamed - I am currently using a dataframe.

The df looks like the below:
+----------+----------+------------+
| Original |   New    | HasChanged |
+----------+----------+------------+
| Name1    | NewName1 |          0 |
| Name2    | NewName2 |          1 |
+----------+----------+------------+

There will be 50,000+ rows in the df. Is there a way to execute an os command (such as os.rename or os.path.join) on all of the rows where HasChanged == 0? In other words, is it possible to vectorize this operation? If so, how would I start this?

Thanks for your help!

I am currently using a for loop along the lines of:

```
for i in df.index:
    if df.at[i, 'HasChanged'] != 1:
         old_path = os.path.join(some_path, df.at[i, 'Original']
         new_path = os.path.join(some_path, df.at[i, 'New'])
         os.rename(old_path, new_path)
```

Comment: simple answer: no